# "install android sdk" checkbox is missing while installing the android studio application

Tags: android, sdk

recently i was installing android studio 3.0.0 in windows 10, and there is no checkbox for installing android sdk.

on the official android website, there is a tutorial video, in that video one can easily see that there are three check-boxes while installing android studio....
[screen shot of android website tutorial video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAafm.jpg)

one more doubt is that, in the video, it shows that required space is greater than 4gb while, in my case, my installation window says 2gb of space is required....[screenshot of installation window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS3k4.png)
please help....

and please help me with choosing the right java version  , thanks a lot in advance....

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was, that i updated my windows 10 to the latest version(from the UPDATE tool), and android studio started to work fine....
i guess this was due to any missed files during my initial windows installation....
i was really getting frustrated over this....

thank God, it is now solved!!!!